# Trigger mvn spring-boot:run from different maven project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have a project structure in following format. Each of them is maven project and MainProject has a pom.xml which will trigger build process of each child project.

MainProject

|------ ChildProject1

|------ ChildProject2

|------ ChildProject3

Right now my ChildProject3 are integration tests which can run only if my service is running. And this service is part of my ChildProject2. So when ChildProject3 runs I want to make a spring-boot:run call of ChildProject2 before ChildProject3 starts running.
I tried adding the following code to my pom.xml of ChildProject3 but it still doesn't trigger the spring-boot:run

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>mvn</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-f</argument>
                    <argument>../ChildProject2/pom.xml</argument>
                    <argument>spring-boot:run</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: spring-boot:run launches `main` command from one of your classes. So you can call the same method in test preparation method

Comment: Thanks for the response @michaldo!
I had tried that as well calling the main method in (at)Before method of my test file. But it was giving me following error.

'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#defaultViewResolver due to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package'

Comment: That is another issue. Maybe here you will found a hint: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/boot/748735-trouble-migrating-spring-integration-project-to-use-spring-boot